# How to post from Android data to Mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have an android application which you can upload a video after logging in. I'm trying track users and insert a mysql query when they upload a video. So basically, how do i post the username to the PHP file when a user uploads a video?

Upload.java

```
public class Upload {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL= "mylinkishere.com/upload.php";

private int serverResponseCode;

public String uploadVideo(String file) {

    String fileName = file;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    File sourceFile = new File(file);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
        return null;
    }

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                    .getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }else {
        return "Could not upload";
    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
    package net.simplifiedcoding.androidloginlogout;

 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener  {

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private TextView textView2;
private TextView edtTc;
private TextView textViewResponse;

private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 3;

private String selectedPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");

    //Showing the current logged in email to textview
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textViewResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResponse);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void chooseVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Video Seçin "), SELECT_VIDEO);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
            System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            textView.setText(selectedPath);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}

private void uploadVideo() {
    class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog uploading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            uploading = ProgressDialog.show(ProfileActivity.this, "Yükleniyor", "Lütfen bekleyin...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            uploading.dismiss();
            textViewResponse.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Yüklendi:  <a href='" + s + "'>" + s + "</a></b>"));
            textViewResponse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Upload u = new Upload();
            String msg = u.uploadVideo(selectedPath);
            return msg;
        }
    }
    UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
    uv.execute();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        chooseVideo();
    }
    if (v == buttonUpload) {
        uploadVideo();
    }
}

//Textview to show currently logged in user
private TextView textView;

//Logout function
private void logout(){
    //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Çıkış yapmak mı istiyorsunuz?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Evet",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    //Getting out sharedpreferences
                    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    //Getting editor
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                    //Puting the value false for loggedin
                    editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                    //Putting blank value to email
                    editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");

                    //Saving the sharedpreferences
                    editor.commit();

                    //Starting login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Hayır",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    //Showing the alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menuLogout) {
        logout();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My upload.php file

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

        $location = "uploads/";

        move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$file_name);
        echo "mylink.com/video/uploads/".$file_name;
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add username as header information

```
conn.setRequestProperty("username", username);
```

Now you can get the header within upload.php

```
$android_username = $_SERVER['HTTP_username'];
```

and write it to your mysql db:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads (username, filename)
VALUES (?,?)";

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $android_username, $file_name);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! Edited for correctness.

Comment: Now that's how you do it!